# unity внутри игровые покупки

Tags: android, ios, unity3d

**Вопрос:** **Есть ли разница между настройкой(IAP) внутри игровых покупок для Android и IOS?**

Нашел огромное количество материала по андроиду,но не по ios.

Возможно что-то упустил,если есть у кого-то полезные ссылки(кроме официальной документации) на статьи и тд скиньте пожалуйста(желательно не 2017-2018 гг).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти нет разницы, если пользоваться готовым [UnityIAP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAP.html). [Официальный туториал](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game).

Там, разве что, структура ответа отличается. Но если вы на свои серваки посылать receipt на валидацию не собираетесь, то и это не важно.

Answer (score 1):

Покупки в Unity для iOS и Android встраиваются одинакова. Единственное отличие, что для iOS нужно обязательно добавить кнопку Восстановления покупок, иначе модерацию не пройдете. [урок по интеграции покупок](https://iunity3d.ru/dobavlenie-vnutriigrovyh-pokupok-v-unity-3d/) можно почитать и посмотреть здесь